# How to forward a request to another server with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, servlets

I have a client and a server. the client side only contains UI and view layer along with controller. the server side contains the services and repository layer and more complicated stuffs. now the user send a request to client side with following controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
   @ResponseBody
   public String save(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

      return CallWebService.callWebServiceUrl(request);
   }
```

but the controller from the server side has the controller for this url as bellow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public CoaChartAccount save(@RequestBody MyObject object) {

      service.save(objCoaChartAccount);
      return object;
   }
```

Now I'm wonder how to pass the request from client contains request payload to such a controller on the other side?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ It doesn't look like you have tried and failed to achieve something.

Answer (score 2):

The client side controller will have to use the RestTemplate to post data to a web service, see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-client-access for more details.

For example, your client controller should look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveClient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public CoaChartAccount save(@RequestBody CoaChartAccount object) throws IOException {
   return restTemplate.postForObject(URL_SAVING_MYOBJECT, object, CoaChartAccount.class);
}
```

The server being the same as you specified (a standard rest web service):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveServer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public CoaChartAccount save(@RequestBody CoaChartAccount object) {

  service.save(object);
  return object;
```

}